# Would running the command "rm -R /" in a Unix-like system completely wipe the partition?

Tags: bash, unix

The title pretty much asks it all. I assume, running this command would be catastrophic to a system, and I'm not about to go testing my theory on my machine, just curious about the power of the `-R` recursive option with `rm`.

Comment: The partition would not be wiped. The filesystem would still be there, just without any files.

Comment: You can run it on any temporary directory to see the effect of -R or use it on root directory in vm

Comment: So there are filesystem files above even the / (root) of my partition? I thought a lot of the filesystem was stored in directories such as /System and /bin, those would not be affected by -R or are not necessary to run the system?

Comment: Nothing exists *above* `/`. A user with permissions to delete files anywhere (like root) would delete *every* modifiable file on the filesystem (filesystems mounted read-only would not be affected). This wouldn't remove the filesystem itself (the fact that files can live there) however and wouldn't (immediately) cause the system to keel over and die (though it would do that fairly quickly thereafter).

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you accepted an answer without verifying it is correct ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm -R /
```

would wipe out all files/folders which the current shell (in which you are running the code) has write access to (excluding some special cases file).

```
rm -Rf /
```

would wipe out all files/folders which the current shell (in which you are running the code) has write access to (regardless of the condition of the files).

So if your run the above command in a root shell or with `sudo`, your entire disk will be emptied (The partitions which are not mounted will be spared).

Answer (score 2):

If you have sufficient privileges, this command will remove all files in the entire filesystem; but that is not equivalent to "wipe the partition". If you want a partition to be completely empty, you also need to remove the empty filesystem, and strictly  speaking perhaps the partition table, too.

There may be multiple mounted file systems on multiple partitions, too; so "the partition" isn't really correct or well-defined in that respect, either. Removing everything recursively will affect all mounted partitions, via their respective mount points.

A filesystem could in theory merely mark the file system entries as deleted, but not actually overwrite anything except the directory entries. This is the reason "undelete" utilities for some file system types can be fairly successful. On most  native U*x filesystems, however, this is not how things usually are set up.

Comment: Just for funsies: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX iflag=nocache oflag=direct bs=4096`

Answer (score 1):

No, on most Unix machines, this command has no catastrophic effects unlike the replies so far are telling.

Not that I want you to experiment on your production server but assuming you run a recent enough POSIX compliant (eg: [Solaris 10](https://blogs.oracle.com/jbeck/date/20041001#rm_rf_protection), 11) or Linux distribution that uses a GNU rm [newer than 2006](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=aff5a4f2ab86f2a51db8f1d1d734406dc4bd8fb3)), this command won't do anything.

The POSIX standard [states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html#tag_20_111):

*... or if an operand resolves to the root directory, rm shall write a diagnostic message to standard error and do nothing more with such operands.*

Should you really want to experiment with removing your whole filesystem, you need, with GNU `rm`, to add the `--no-preserve-root` option. Alternatively, you can use something different than `/`, say `/*` `/.??*` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't include -f, so it'll probably stop to ask confirmation pretty early on when it hits a system file with filesystem protection.

But beyond that, assuming you also run as root/sudo: Yes, this will delete not only the current root partition, but also any other partitions you have mounted.

(If your intent is to actually wipe the specific partition (or alternatively the whole drive), learn the 'dd' command.  Carefully. ;))